# indexOf cause java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a user list stored on a file, when I want to add a parameter to the user I

```
ArrayList<User> list = loadListFromfile();
System.out.println("USER LIST: "+ list);

//the user to update
User oldUser = getCurrentUser();
System.out.println("CURRENT USER: "+ oldUser);

//update user receives an user and an update param and returns the updated user
User newUser = updateUser(oldUser, "updateparam");
System.out.println("NEW USER: "+ newUser);

//replace the old user with the new one
list.set(list.indexOf(oldUser), newUser);
```

All the prints returns correct values but when I invoke

```
list.set(list.indexOf(oldUser), newUser);
```

The app crashes with this error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
```

This is really strange and I cannot understand the reason of the issue, in addition list has only 2 items (not 12).

How could I fix this?

Comment: But in this case the list is not empty and println, prints all values correctly... so really I cannot understand why I get this error

Comment: oops, my bad.. your list is not empty indeed..
but your `oldUser`'s index is invalid..
are you sure that oldUser is inside the list..?
perhaps just a matter of white spaces or something..?

Comment: because `oldUser` was not inside the `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexOf(oldUser) returns -1 if the oldUser is not found. In that case, set(-1) will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: but getCurrentUser(); returns the current user that I want to update... and the System.out.println("CURRENT USER: "+ oldUser); prints the right value. So why doesn't find the user?

Comment: What is the code for getCurrentUser()? Is it looking in the list? Also, can updateUser() remove the oldUser from the list? You should print out the values in the list, to debug.

Comment: `getCurrentUser` load the file where user list is saved (that is the same file accessed by `loadListFromfile();` in this piece of code) and get the User where the names matches with a string name saved in Prefs

Comment: how about `updateUser()`? does it remove the old user from the list..?

Comment: no simply takes the `oldUser` object, updates some Strings and values, and returns the new Object

Comment: "new Object"? Sounds like you replaced oldUser with a new object? If so, then the set() call may not even be necessary...

Comment: no old user is not replaced, is only passed to a method and copied, the method is in another class and cannot access oldUser directly.

Comment: the way you "update" seems fishy, could you share it with us..?

Comment: ok I have checked the update method more accurately, and yes update oldUser, so this cause the mismatch. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should add the oldUser to the list. The error information shows that the oldUser doesn't exist in the list.
Please add

```
list.add(oldUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

`oldUser` **is not coming as -1**, but it is not present in the `list`. That's why its throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
As per code `System.out.println("CURRENT USER: "+ oldUser);` it will not print -1.

**Update:**

```
 list.indexOf(oldUser) // Returning -1.
```

Here index of `oldUser` in list returns the index at which the value of `oldUser` present. The actual value of `oldUser` is not present in your `list`, that's why its returning `-1`.

```
list.set(-1, newUser);
```

When it try to set anything in -1 location, its throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: but `getCurrentUser();` returns the current user that I want to update... and the `System.out.println("CURRENT USER: "+ oldUser);` prints the right value

Comment: @AndreaF Can you please debug once and check the value of oldUser just before list.set(list.indexOf(oldUser), newUser); line?

Comment: see my code... the `System.out.println("CURRENT USER: "+ oldUser);` is before the list set. and is printed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that `list.indexOf(oldUser)` is returning -1, which is in fact an array index out of bounds. How do you obtain oldUser? Could we get the code on `getCurrentUser()`?

Also, any chance that `updateUser(oldUser, "updateparam")` is messing up with the list? It should work whether it returns a pointer to a new user or a pointer to the old user (the same pointer you're passing in the first argument), and it should work whether it modifies the actual object pointed at by oldUser parameter or not.

Basically I fear you might be facing an issue with oldUser.equals(e) for every e contained in the list [which is called in the contains method of ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29). But can't really say without the code. You might find it with this idea though.